# Why is my Flask API returning none in the html

Tags: python, data-science

I am having issues understanding Flask API's and what is needed to return the required information. I can print the data such as:

```
crunchbaseNY = crunchbase[crunchbase['city'] == 'New York']
print(crunchbaseNY)
```

but when put into Flask it is returned as 'None'

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask("MyApp")

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    output = print(crunchbaseNY)
    return render_template('index.html', result=output)
    #return output
    
app.run(host='localhost', port=5001)
```

Comment: `print()` returns `None`, for starters

Comment: What should I use instead to have it display the information correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did

```
output = print(crunchbaseNY)
```

print do print and return None, please change it to

```
output = str(crunchbaseNY)
```